# Standardizing dates in long format dataframe

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a data frame containing daily COVID cases and deaths for each state of Brazil, like this:

```
state   date                cases            deaths
 RO 2020-03-20               1                0
 RO 2020-03-21               1                0
 RO 2020-03-22               3                0
 RO 2020-03-23               3                0
 RO 2020-03-24               3                0
 RO 2020-03-25               5                0
```

My problem is that the states start on different dates, even though all of them end on 2020-05-24. For instance, `RO` starts on 2020-03-20 but `AC` starts on 2020-03-19. Is there any technique I can use to standardize them so that every state starts on 2020-02-26?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that 'date' is `Date` class, one ption would be `complete`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(state, region) %>%
   complete(date = seq(as.Date('2020-02-26'), last(date), by = '1 day')) %>%
   ungroup
```

By default, the missing dates added with `complete` would have other columns i.e. 'cases', 'deaths' for those rows as `NA` unless we change with `fill` argument

Comment: Excellent, this i what i need! Just one more thing i forgot to ask: my dataframe also has a column indicating the region to which the state belongs. Is it possible to tell the complete function to fill the extra lines with the corresponding regions?

Comment: @RodrigoDias May be you need `group_by(state, region)`